# Orthodox und Ultraorthodox

Tags: vocabulary

Wieso gibt es auch das Wort "Ultraorthodox". Orthodox ist man doch, wenn man etwas weiter rechts von "streng gläubig" steht. Wieso muss man dann auch noch ein Ultra davorstellen?

Wird man bald auch zwischen Rechtsextremisten und Ultrarechtsextremisten unterscheiden? Ich finde es nur komisch, dass man jetzt noch ein "Ultra" "Mega" vor Sachen packt, die in meinen Augen keinen Sinn ergeben.

Hoffentlich kann mir jemand helfen. Wieso haben wir jetzt "Ultraorthodoxe"?

Comment: Was meinst Du mit "jetzt" im letzten Satz? Willst Du sagen, das sei eine jüngere Sprachschöpfung?

Comment: Vergleichen wir mal orthodoxes Judentum mit Rechtsextremismus, super Idee.

Answer (score 5):

### Orthodox

»Orthodox« bedeutet nicht, dass jemand »etwas rechts von *streng gläubig* steht«. Griechisch- oder russisch-orthodoxe Christen sind keine politisch rechten Christen, und sie hängen ihrem Glauben auch nicht strenger an als Katholiken oder Baptisten, Mormonen usw.

»Orthodox« bedeutet, dass die Anhänger einer Lehre, die sich im Lauf der Zeit in mehrere Strömungen aufgespalten hat, sich weiterhin an die ursprüngliche, traditionelle Auslegung halten. Im Gegensatz dazu hängen Erneuerer einer Lehrmeinung an, die nicht allein auf jahrtausendealten Büchern beruht, sondern sich auch den stetig wandelnden Gegebenheiten der Umwelt Rechnung trägt.

### Mission

Nun gibt es bei allen religiösen Glaubensrichtungen Anhänger, die meinen, sie müssen das, was sie persönlich für richtig halten, unbedingt auch dem Rest der Welt beibringen.

In der milden, anerkannten Form ist das die Missionierung. Dabei geht ein Missionar hinaus in die Welt und versucht die, die seinem Glauben nicht anhängen, durch Gespräche von seinem Glauben zu überzeugen. Die Zeugen Jehova sind beispielsweise für ihre besonders intensive Missionarstätigkeit bekannt.

### politisch rechts

Dann gibt es aber auch religiöse Fanatiker, die versuchen, denen, die nicht so denken wie sie, mit Gewalt ihre Anschauungen einzuprügeln, und notfalls die, die sich ihnen dabei in den Weg stellen, zu töten. Diese Tötung wird damit gerechtfertigt, dass diese Menschen ungläubig und damit minderwertig sind. Diese Idee, es gäbe minderwertige Menschen, die wegen ihrer Wertlosigkeit verfolgt und sogar getötet werden dürfen, ist, politisch gesehen, nun tatsächlich rechts.

Das hat allerdings mit Orthodoxie nichts zu tun. Die Christen, die im Mittelalter in mehreren Wellen auf ihren Kreuzzügen massenhaft Menschen abgeschlachtet haben, waren keine orthodoxen Christen, sondern Katholiken. Viele von Ihnen haben in ihrer Mordgier übrigens nicht nur Moslems und Juden, sondern auch Christen abgeschlachtet. Man wollte sich nicht lange damit aufhalten, die Religionszugehörigkeit herauszufinden, und vertraute darauf, dass Gott im Himmel ohnehin die »guten« (Christen) von dem unwerten Nicht-Christen trennen wird, und die ermordeten Christen im Himmel als Märtyrer anerkennen wird.

### Ultraorthodox, ultrakonservativ

Die lateinische Vorsilbe »ultra« bedeutet »mehr« oder »darüber hinaus«. Ultraviolettes Licht ist eine elektromagnetische Strahlung mit einer Frequenz, die über die des gewöhnlichen violetten Lichts hinaus geht. Ultraschall ist die Bezeichnung für Töne, die so hoch sind, dass sie über das menschliche Hörvermögen hinaus gehen.

Wenn jemand ultra-konservativ ist, heißt das, dass er konservativ ist, und sein Konservatismus über das übliche Maß hinaus geht. Konservative Menschen versuchen althergebrachte Werte zu bewahren. Das tun ultrakonservative Menschen auch. Letztere versuchen aber gleichzeitig auch, alle Neuerungen zu verhindern, weil sie ihrer Meinung nach die alten Werte gefährden. Zum Schutz der alten Werte sind sie bereit Maßnahmen gegen die Neuerungen zu ergreifen, die von gewöhnlichen Konservativen nicht gebilligt würden.

Wenn die Werte, die von solchen Menschen verteidigt werden, religiöse Werte sind, wenn es sich also um orthodoxe Menschen handelt, dann spricht man von ultra-orthodoxen Menschen.

### Abgrenzung rechts – orthodox

Ich möchte aber noch einmal herausstreichen, dass Orthodoxie und Ultra-Orthodoxie nichts mit einer politisch rechten Gesinnung zu tun haben:

Wer politisch rechts ist, ist davon überzeugt, dass es Menschen gibt, die minderwertig sind, und wegen dieser Minderwertigkeit angegriffen und eventuell sogar getötet werden dürfen. Wer politisch rechts denkt, fühlt sich also einer hochwertigen Gruppe von Menschen zugehörig.

Wer orthodox ist, denkt nicht darüber nach, ob Menschen mehr oder weniger wert sind als man selbst. Wer orthodox ist, versucht alte religiöse Lehren nach alten Interpretationen auszuleben. Das ist sehr mit Konservatismus verwandt, wo generell versucht wird, alte Werte zu bewahren (konservare = bewahren), egal ob religiös oder nicht.

Wer ultraorthodox ist, glaubt, dass die alten religiösen Werte, die er bewahren möchte, in Gefahr sind. Daraus resultiert eine Bereitschaft, diese alten Werte notfalls mit Gewalt gegen tatsächliche oder eingebildete Angreifer zu verteidigen.

Natürlich kann es dazu kommen, dass orthodoxe Menschen die Menschen, die ihre alten Werte nicht so achten wie sie selbst, für minderwertig halten, und somit rechts im politischen Sinne denken. Aber dieser Schritt ist nicht zwingend in der Orthodoxie enthalten. Im Gegenteil: Im Rahmen der Ökumene sind orthodoxe Juden, orthodoxe Christen und orthodoxen Moslems durchaus bereit, auch mit Anhängern moderner religiöser Lehren zusammen zu arbeiten.

Comment: Schön wie Du zeigst, dass OP in der Frage versuchte, Äpfel mit Birnen zu vergleichen! Man sollte wirklich vorsichtig sein, was man in einen Topf wirft, weil die Mischung sonst *explosiv* werden könnte.

Comment: Rechts denken bedeutet, die persönliche Freiheit und Verantwortung höher zu achten als diejenige des Staates (verkürzt gesagt). Links denkende Menschen sind oft sehr untolerant gegen weniger tolerant denkende Menschen, was sie nicht nach rechts rückt. Wenn politisch rechts tatsächlich mit der Verfolgung andersdenkender zu tun hätte, und die Linke davor gefeit wäre, erkläre bitte die kommunistische Revolution, die DDR, die chinesische Kulturrevolution. Die Frage des OP wurde ansonsten gut beantwortet.

Comment: Mission ist so weit ich weiß ein christliches Problem ohne jüdische Entsprechung. Ich weiß allerdings nicht, wie es mit innerjüdischer Werbung aussieht.

Comment: @RalphM.Rickenbach: Die eigene individuelle Freiheit über alles andere zu stellen kommt einer Ablehnung jeder Regierungsform gleich, und das ist Anarchie. Anarchie wird politisch aber als links (also das Gegenteil von rechts) angesehen. Der Kommunismus in seiner extremsten Auslegung sah vor, dass alle Menschen gleich sind, und jeglicher Besitz der Allgemeinheit gehören sollte, was natürlich zu Konflikten mit anders denkenden (den »Kapitalisten«) führte. Soweit mit bekannt ist, hat man diese Andersdenkenden aber nicht als minderwertig angesehen, sondern als feindlich, und sie deswegen bekämpft.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Über jüdische Missionare weis ich auch nichts, aber islamische Missionare gibt es. Eine Gruppe von missionierenden Moslems sind die Salafisten, man kann sie gelegentlich in Fußgängerzonen beim Koran-Verteilen sehen. In Wien zieht bei schönem Wetter beinahe täglich eine Gruppe von ca. 10 Hare-Krischna-Anhängern durch die Mariahilfer-Straße und plärrt ihr Mantra, dank Verstärkerbox gut 500 Meter weit hörbar, in die Gegend, begleitet von Freiwilligen, die ihre Flyer jedem in die Hand drücken, der nicht schnell genug ausweicht. Das ist auch nicht-christliche Missionstätigkeit.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, richtig, es ist keine rein christliche Eigenheit. Aber sehr vereinfacht haben Christen ein Jesuswort, sie sollen Menschen fischen, während Juden sich für das auserwählte Volk halten.

Comment: Ich habe von serbisch-orthodoxen Christen, von griechisch-orthodoxen und russisch-orthodoxen gehört, dagegen nie von ultra-orthodexen. Von ultra-orthodoxen Juden und orthodoxen Juden dagegen schon. Anfangs wusste ich nicht, dass da eine klare Trennung besteht und habe das einfach als radikal und sehr radikal interpretiert. Dem ist aber, wie ich inzw. gelernt habe, nicht so. Haredim (ultraorthodoxe Juden) sind (oder waren) etwa vom Militärdienst befreit (im Ggs. zu orthodoxen Juden) was heißt, dass es objektive Kriterien geben muss, wonach man das eine oder das andere ist.

Comment: @userunknown... könntest du das nicht in eine Antwort gießen, die den ern hat, dass "ultraorthodox" ein fester Terminus ist, dessen Bedeutung nur bedingt der Summe der Teile entspricht? Hubert... warum der Abschnitt über "Mission"?

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich habe die Überschriften erst nachträglich in den bereits fertig geschriebenen Fließtext eingefügt, um ihn zu gliedern und damit leichter lesbar zu machen. Der dritte und vierte Absatz passten aber weder unter die Überschrift »*Orthodox*« noch unter »*rechts*«. Diese beiden Absätze leiteten aber zum Thema »*rechts*« über, so dass ich sie auch nicht wegstreichen wollte. Also ließ ich sie stehen, und verpasste ihnen eine eigene Überschrift. Dadurch treten diese beiden Absätze jetzt leider stärker hervor als es ihrem Inhalt entspricht, aber insgesamt war es imho doch die beste Lösung.

Comment: Danke, @Emanuel, für die Ermunterung, aber erstens bin ich in dem Thema jetzt auch nicht wirklich firm. Zweitens wird in der Frage gar nicht speziell nach dem Judentum gefragt. Mit dem Wikipediaartikel zu ultraorthodoxen Juden ist man sicher besser bedient.

Answer (score 3):

*Ultra-* ist hier einfach noch eine weitere Steigerung. Jemand ist nicht einfach "nur" orthodox, also strenggläubig (ich kenne das eigentlich nur im religiösen Kontext, bei Juden), sondern in ganz starkem, um nicht zu sagen übersteigertem Ausmaß:

> Ultraorthodoxe Juden stehen weltlichem Wissen ablehnend gegenüber und führen ein streng reguliertes, meist auf ein rabbinisches Oberhaupt ausgerichtetes Leben abseits der Mainstream-Gesellschaft, sowohl der jüdischen wie nichtjüdischen (sagt [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraorthodoxes_Judentum))

Ob das nun logisch ist, oder nicht, herrschender Sprachgebrauch ist es jedenfalls.

Comment: Ich meine es ist nicht einfach eine weitere Steigerung, wie etwa bei "Es ist heiß heute", "Ja sehr heiß", "Ich würde gar sagen ultraheiß", sondern es gibt feste Gruppenzugehörigkeiten, und es ist keine subjektive Sache, ob ein orthodoxer Jude ultraorthodox ist oder nicht, sondern eine strikte Gruppenzugehörigkeit zu den Haredim.

Comment: Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch bedeutet die Vorsilbe _ultra_ "über ... hinaus". Das trifft m. E.  zu, da hier nicht mehr von bloßer Orthodoxie gesprochen werden kann. Man muss ansonsten mit den politischen und religiösen Details des Judentums nicht übermäßig vertraut sein, um diesen Begriff zu verwenden oder doch jedenfalls zu verstehen.

Comment: Die Bezeichnung _orthodox_ war einfach schon belegt, als die Strömung aufkam.

Comment: Das Wort _orthodox_ im Zusammenhand mit der christlichen Religion wird überlicherweise nicht mit _strenggläubig_ sondern mit _rechtgläubig_ übersetzt. Vergleiche auch das russische Wort _православний_ , welches genau diese letztere Bedeutung hat.